# What is '컴퓨터 세탁'?

Tags: vocabulary

[**컴퓨터 세탁**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?biw=1548&bih=753&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=cJr2Wb2nAci48QWoiIXgBg&q=%EC%BB%B4%ED%93%A8%ED%84%B0%20%EC%84%B8%ED%83%81&oq=%EC%BB%B4%ED%93%A8%ED%84%B0%20%EC%84%B8%ED%83%81) shops are a common sight - but what is '컴퓨터 세탁'? I haven't seen an equivalent English term 'Computer Dry Cleaning'.

Comment: I think it just means the washing machine is computer controlled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not as common as before to see "컴퓨터" before "세탁" nowadays when you walk down the streets because "computer" is not as rare as before.

Dry cleaner's in the past (probably before 90's) used a manual dry cleaner to dry clean clothes, but after automated technology developed, they all used an automated dry cleaning machine. The word "automated" or the sentence "you don't have to do anything from the beginning to the end for this machine and just start it" got translated into "컴퓨터' which was a very cool word in that era.

Nowadays, all people know how the washing machines work and you don't need to use the word any more. If you find any laundry shop with "컴퓨터 세탁", it means they have been operational at least for a couple of decades. I don't remember seeing it recently.